# Rotated border based triangle rendering in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, rendering

When I make a css triangle it's all good, but when I rotate it a strange line appears in the middle. Why is this?

[image]

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uausv85h/2/).

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    width:0; 
    height:0; 
    border:100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    border-top-color:#333;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Why rotate the triangle, why not just use a different border?

Comment: add translate3d( 0, 0, 1px) - https://jsfiddle.net/g3ahcryn/

Comment: @Paulie, I am using this as a part of a much bigger animation and i have 4 triangles faced in 4 different ways. Anyway, I am curious, how exactly can I achieve that shape without rotation?

Comment: its bug - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=818109

Comment: Ok, you can write that as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its bug - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=818109

add `translate3d( 0, 0, 1px)`

```css
div {
    position:absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border: 100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    border-top-color: #333;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 1px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 1px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 1px);        
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```